# Filter by number of occurrences in a SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, having-clause

Given the following table where the `Name` value might be repeated in multiple rows:

[image: The table]

How can we determine how many times a `Name` value exists in the table and can we filter on *names* that have a specific number of occurrances.

For instance, how can I filter this table to show only *names* that appear twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having` to exhibit `name`s that appear twice in the table:

```
select name, count(*) cnt
from mytable
group by name
having count(*) = 2
```

Then if you want the overall count of names that appear twice, you can add another level of aggregation:

```
select count(*) cnt
from (
    select name
    from mytable
    group by name
    having count(*) = 2
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a histogram of the frequency of name counts.  Something like this

```
with counts_cte(name, cnt) as (
    select name, count(*) 
    from mytable
    group by name)
select cnt, count(*) num_names
from counts_cte
group by cnt
order by 2 desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a GROUP BY clause to find counts of name repeated as

```
select name, count(*) AS Repeated
from Your_Table_Name
group by name;
```

If You want to show only those Which are repeated more than one times. Then use the below query which will show those occurrences which are there more than one times.

```
select name, count(*) AS Repeated
from Your_Table_Name
group by name having count(*) > 1;
```